# HAProxy load balance

Tags: haproxy, keep-alive

I trying to use haproxy to loadbalance 2 virtual machines. To avoid confusion, yes I have to 2 virtual machines and on both of them I have installed these components "HAProxy", "Keepalived" and "web application". Futhermore I have configured Floating IP.

So basic flow I want to achieve is - Master "HaProxy" takes all requests coming from "Floating IP" and load balance traffic. "Keepalived" checks if master server is online, I want to direct traffic to my second VM "HAProxy".

My question how to direct traffic to Backup VM HAProxy if master fails?

Comment: If anyone ran in similar problem consider reading : http://backreference.org/2012/04/25/load-balancing-and-ha-for-multiple-applications-with-apache-haproxy-and-keepalived/